# NHiberante not able to delete child entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 entities mapped one to many in NHibernate. Here is the mapping in Parent entity:

```
HasMany(x => x.RepairShopWeekDayProperties).KeyColumn("RepairShopId").AsSet().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

and here is the mapping in child entity:

```
  Map(x => x.RepairShopId).Column("RepairShopId").Not.Insert().Not.Update(); 
  References(x => x.RepairShop).Column("RepairShopId").Not.Nullable();
```

When I'm trying to delete all WeekDayProperties assigned to repair shop like this:

```
rs.RepairShopWeekDayProperties.Clear();
```

I see that WeekDayProperty entities are not beeng deleted on transaction commit - NHibernate just trying to set RepairShopId to null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make all that working you should use `inverse="true"` setting:

```
HasMany(x => x.RepairShopWeekDayProperties)
   .Inverse() // here we go
   .KeyColumn("RepairShopId")
   .AsSet()
   .Cascade
   .AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Check this for more details: [21.3. Cascading lifecycle](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-cascades)